# Git: How to order files by least to most unstaged changes

Tags: git

Is there a way to order files in "git status" from least to most changes? I often come back to projects days later and find uncommitted changes, and it would be nice if I could commit the simpler changes first before having to deal with the more complicated changes. Right now I find myself having to run "git diff" on files one by one to find out which have the simplest changes.

Comment: `simpler changes` - How will you define simple ?

Comment: What if those simple changes are connected with other changes? If you `git checkout` you won't have what you need to run the code properly. A clean commit should consists of related changes and not just changes to a specific file. You change the main code, but forget the unit test (or do the reverse), then something will fail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `--numstat` option of `git diff` to have a count of added/removed lines per file.

To get the count for *staged* files, add `--cached` : `git diff --cached --numstat`

---

You can process the output as you like :

for example, you can add the two numbers, and sort by decreasing order :

`git git diff --cached --numstat  | awk '{ print $1+$2"\t"$3 } | sort -rn`

Answer (score 1):

No.  I don't see any way to way to modify the order of the `git status` output.  You could write your [custom](http://thediscoblog.com/blog/2014/03/29/custom-git-commands-in-3-steps/) status command, however, and figure out number of changes for each file from `git diff`